# Python3.5 - как запустить асинхронную функцию, не ожидая её завершения?

Tags: python-3.5, asyncio

Есть приложение, обрабатыващее твиты, получаемые посредством streaming api.
Обработка твита проходит в отдельной функции вида

```
async def process_tweet(text):
  ...

async for tweet in stream:
  await process_tweet(tweet['text'])
```

Но - соответственно, приложение готово к обработке нового твита только по завершении обработки прошлого.
При этом параллельная обработка нескольких твитов не должна быть проблемой - соответственно, хотелось бы реализовать это. То есть что-то типа

```
async def process_tweet(text):
  ...

async for tweet in stream:
  run_without_waiting(process_tweet(tweet['text']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Через [ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) обычно. Но тут есть нюанс. Она не выполнится сразу, а уложится на стек и выполнится до вызова следующей асинхронной функции.
Это годится для коротких функций.
Чтоб она выполнилась в фоне лучше посмотреть на [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor)